# Is it possible to only render a percentage of a GradientBrush?

Tags: wpf, rendering, brush, lineargradientbrush

Consider the following `LinearGadientBrush`, 'A'.  Normally, if you specify that brush as the background of a rectangle, it fills the entire area with the entire gradient, regardless of the size. (See B).

We're trying to say 'For this particular control, only utilize the first xx% of the brush for the fill' so we can achieve a percentage-based gradient fill, like in 'C'.

[image]

Note: We know we're going to be responsible for which percentage to show since there's no way for the system to automatically calculate what a percentage represents.

The way we are currently doing this is shown in 'D'.  We define a rectangle at 100% the size we need (so the fill is 100%), then place it inside another control and left-align it. We then set the outer control's `ClipsToBounds` to true, and set its width to the desired percentage of the inner rectangle's width. (See D)  This approach works, but adds extra elements in the visual tree which we're trying to eliminate if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the EndPoint property of the LinearGradientBrush. In your case if you set `EndPoint="2,0"` you should get the desired result you are looking for.

If you need to do something more dynamic you can bind a point object to the EndPoint property. If you set the value to 1,0 it will show 100% of the gradient or 2,0 to show the first 50% of the gradient.

`StartPoint` allows you to do the same thing on the other side of the gradient.

Comment: Close, but there's one issue here.  Since StartPoint and EndPoint are properties of the brush itself, you would need one instance of the brush per value rendered. Still, voting yours up for the info, even though it's not an exact fit since it led me to the answer I just posted which uses MappingMode to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  It's the brush's MappingMode.  If you set it to Absolute, it renders in actual coordinates and not as a percentage of the control itself, meaning if your 'full' width is 240 units, you'd set the end point to 240. (Note the GradientStop offsets are always a percentage of the distance between StartPoint and EndPoint.)

The down-side is you need one brush per 'width' of controls you want to render, meaning if you have ten bar graphs at 200 units wide and six more at 150 units wide, you'd need two brushes, one for each width.

Here's an example from MSDN...

```
<!-- The MappingMode property is set to "Absolute" which specifies that the coordinate 
     system used for the StartPoint and EndPoint properties is not relative to the 
     Brush output area. Values are interpreted directly in local space. -->

<!-- Create a brush that is absolutely 200 units wide -->
<LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" 
    StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="200,0">

    <GradientStop Color="Yellow"    Offset="0"    />
    <GradientStop Color="Red"       Offset="0.25" />
    <GradientStop Color="Blue"      Offset="0.75" />
    <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1"    />

</LinearGradientBrush>
```